# Verb + ing at the start of the sentence

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

These phrases follow the pattern Verb + 'ing' + Noun

1. Visiting my hometown.
2. Visiting Tokyo.
3. Doing my homework.

They are titles of things and don't have any other written context. I can provide some context from the places I saw them.

1. This is a title of a video of Pewdiepie.
2. 10 things to know before visiting Tokyo.
3. Doing my homework is the thing I like.

What are the meanings of these sentences(or phrases)?

Comment: Where did you find them?  If they are Tweets or similar, you should infer “I am …” in front.

Comment: They are not complete sentences, and their full meaning cannot be determined without more context.

Answer (score 1):

When an author is creating a title for a video or article or something similar they usually want it to be very short, so that it easily catches the reader's attention. They might be competing with other authors to try to get people to read what they wrote or watch their video. If the title was too long the reader wouldn't bother to read it and they would move on to the next video instead. It's common to use phrases instead of full sentences for this purpose.

As titles, these phrases suggest longer ideas the describe the content of the video or writing. You can think about them as shortened versions of the following

> This video is about **Doing My Homework**
>   This article is about **Visiting Tokyo**
>   This video is about **Visiting My Home Town**

Answer (score 0):

These are not sentences. They may indicate an action, or a time period.

> - I am visiting my hometown this week. (action)
> - While visiting Tokyo I met Mr. Kurosawa. (time period)
> - Doing my homework is almost never interesting. (action)